# Java - Sound Won't Load - AudioInputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, import, audio-streaming

So I took it upon my self to brows Notch's Prelude of the Chambered into Eclipse for study. I had to do some weird work around where I took the resources out of the resource folder to get the game to work and I believe that may be the problem. The game works now but there is no sound. I checked the art input and how he goes about getting the art into the game and it's very similar to the way he gets sound. I assume this is convention among most Java developers and fairly standard but I'm not sure. I seem to be getting the art outside of a resource folder just fine so I'm not sure why the audio would make any difference.

I've tried messing around a lot with the URL or file location rather - example - ("/snd/altar.wav"). I've tried being specific in the location name and moved it outside of the folder and put the sounds in their own resource folder and nothing seems to work.

I believe the problem lies within 
this line "AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResource(fileName));".

The exception I'm getting in the console is multiple 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
I'm pretty sure this means it's not getting a string but I'm not sure.
I've tested to see if it were the play or loadSound method and it was definitely the loadSound that is the problem.

I have come here as a last resort and have searched for similar problems and while I found some informative answers none seem to be directly related to mine.

Also, I'm compiling in 1.7 and this game came out in 2011, but it shouldn't be a problem I don't think because I think I read that the library has been around since a very early version of Java.

Thanks for taking the time to help and anything you can think of is much appreciated. It's not a serious problem as I am able to run and modify the game without sound, but it is rather annoying and I would love to understand why this doesn't work as this is for studying purposes. Again, thanks!

```
package com.mojang.escape;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sound {
    public static Sound altar = loadSound("/snd/altar.wav");
    public static Sound bosskill = loadSound("/snd/bosskill.wav");
    public static Sound click1 = loadSound("/snd/click.wav");
    public static Sound click2 = loadSound("/snd/click2.wav");
    public static Sound hit = loadSound("/snd/hit.wav");
    public static Sound hurt = loadSound("/snd/hurt.wav");
    public static Sound hurt2 = loadSound("/snd/hurt2.wav");
    public static Sound kill = loadSound("/snd/kill.wav");
    public static Sound death = loadSound("/snd/death.wav");
    public static Sound splash = loadSound("/snd/splash.wav");
    public static Sound key = loadSound("/snd/key.wav");
    public static Sound pickup = loadSound("/snd/pickup.wav");
    public static Sound roll = loadSound("/snd/roll.wav");
    public static Sound shoot = loadSound("/snd/shoot.wav");
    public static Sound treasure = loadSound("/snd/treasure.wav");
    public static Sound crumble = loadSound("/snd/crumble.wav");
    public static Sound slide = loadSound("/snd/slide.wav");
    public static Sound cut = loadSound("/snd/cut.wav");
    public static Sound thud = loadSound("/snd/thud.wav");
    public static Sound ladder = loadSound("/snd/ladder.wav");
    public static Sound potion = loadSound("/snd/potion.wav");

    public static Sound loadSound(String fileName) {
        Sound sound = new Sound();
        try {
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResource(fileName));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            sound.clip = clip;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return sound;
    }

    private Clip clip;

    public void play() {
        try {
            if (clip != null) {
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (clip) {
                            clip.stop();
                            clip.setFramePosition(0);
                            clip.start();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Full Stack Trace Output**
I know a lot of it's repetitive (for each unloaded sound). 
But I decided it better to just go ahead and post the full thing since that is what was asked for.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:6)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:7)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:8)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:9)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:10)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:11)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:12)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:13)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:14)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:15)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:16)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:17)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:18)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:19)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:20)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:21)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:22)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:23)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:24)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:25)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.loadSound(Sound.java:33)
    at com.mojang.escape.Sound.(Sound.java:26)
    at com.mojang.escape.menu.TitleMenu.tick(TitleMenu.java:30)
    at com.mojang.escape.Game.tick(Game.java:95)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.tick(EscapeComponent.java:117)
    at com.mojang.escape.EscapeComponent.run(EscapeComponent.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Show us the full stack trace of the error (the output of `e.printStackTrace`)

Comment: @greg-449 I added the stack trace to the end of the question since it was so long. I didn't know the correct way to format so I just left it as is. It's very repetitive, but I decided to post the full and complete console output anyway for good measure. I assume this is meaning there is some issue with pulseaudio?

Comment: @greg-449 This helped me tremendously! Thank you! I now have sound and no errors.  Since I'm very new here should I delete this post because it is a duplicate or leave it up for others? And also is there a way to upvote your helpful link?

Comment: As a gold badge holder I can close this as duplicate. No you can't upvote my link. Glad to help